# Port forwarding with micromax mmx219w plug and play WiFi modem

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding

I'm using a micromax auto plug n play wi fi modem with router functionality,  it provides 8 WiFi connections.

Model: micromax mmx219w WiFi router.

When connected to a USB port, it gets a external IP address, for example `117.225.33.131` from the ISP, and it has the internal login page at `192.168.0.1` for its own menu.

It provides a local IP address to my computer `192.168.0.100` (from its range `192.168.0.100` to `192.168.0.199`).

When I browse for the page `117.225.33.131` (the external IP address)  then it opens the modem login page.

What I want that it should port forward this to my local IP `192.168.0.100:80` on Which I'm running a web server.

I have checked its menu and there is no port forwarding page.

I did put off my McAfee firewall.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your router does not support port forwarding.

Comment: Thanks david. Now is there any alternate to achieve this. like i used the cmd: netsh portproxy add v4tov4..... thats also not working. can't my win7 ultimate 64bit overrun my modem thru this cmd?

Comment: There is no alternative that I know of. You cannot run a public facing server behind this device. By the way if browsing to the public IP address of the router opens its configuration page then this is a big security risk. Hower from the limited information in the user manual this does not seem to be configurable. You should contact MicroMx support http://www.micromaxinfo.com/support.aspx

Comment: thanks again and u are right,  as u wrote "By the way if browsing to the public IP address of the router opens its configuration page then this is a big security risk. ". this is again a issue for me. as if i tell u my router's external ip then u can see my router's login page by typing that ip.

Comment: Last time with another modem and with prepaid sim i started my server from my desktop pc with win7, php, mysql and a simple homepage to just take three entry fields. My friend typed my system's external ip address in his computer sitting remotely and opened my webpage and entered his detail on my web page and my server successfully done sending and receiving. And i eventually test ran a web server from my home without any concerned to host webserver.